# Can I dynamically view images in ruby on rails using an instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

new to ruby on rails and I wanted to know if using an instance to dynamically view an image is at all possible. I wanted to do it like this:

```
 <img src= app/images/“<%= @article.pic %>” >
```

any help or answer would greatly be appreciated

My goal is to display a list of articles. Every article would have a title, body and a pic. When an article is clicked I want the associated image to be displayed on the show page

Comment: It would actually look like, `<img src="app/images/<%= @article.pic %>">`, but when does `@article.pic` change versus when the page is rendered? If you just want the page to grab whatever image is in `@article.pic` any time the page is rendered, then this would work fine. If you want an image on the screen to keep changing dynamically, without re-rendering the page, you'll need to get into some Javascript or similar method.

Comment: I want to link the picture to an article. each article would have title, body and a pic. When a particular article is clicked, I want the associated picture to be displayed in the show section

Comment: You're looking for something like [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for attaching images to records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like paperclip or alternatively ck-editor with paperclip.

- https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

If you're planning only 1 image per article you want to follow the example with the avatar, just replace it with something else. If you want more images in the body I would strongly go with something like ck-editor for simplicity of editing content. This would allow you to add many images in the body of article, however this will not build association between article and images.

If you want multiple images attached to the article you can create another model with attachment (using paperclip)

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :images
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :article
   has_attached_file :attachment
   validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

this way you could call image like this (this would take the first image if there was more than one):

```
<%= image_tag(@article.images.first.attachment.url(:medium)) if @artcile.images.any? %>
```

here best implementation of WYSIWYG editor -ckeditor 
- https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

CATCH: if you run your app on Heroku, you will also have to use something like S3 for file storage. Otherwise files will be stored in the temporary folder and deleted every time you restart your app.

Comment: Sorry to comment on a thread not mine.  @LukaszMuzka I'm wondering where I could find more info about what you mean by using Amazon S3 for file storage if run on heroku.

Comment: That definitely what I wanted/needed for my project. followed a great tutorial. and with an exception of a few changes. it was essentially painless. Paperclip is good.

Comment: I made tutorial on www.peoplecancode.com http://www.peoplecancode.com/en/paths/4/tutorials/25